# Does backbone collection update method (bb 0.9.9) fire a reset event

Tags: backbone.js

Or does it fire another unique event?
Any input on how else could I have figured this out on my own (other then searching stackoverflow and reading bb documentation) is welcome.  10x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Collection.update` doesn't seem to fire any special events. `add` and `remove` events are fired for added and removed models, respectively.

The best way to find out how Backbone works is to read the [annotated backbone source code](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html).